# Allow users coming from a specific link to see private posts in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I have a WordPress blog (self-hosted) and I want the users coming from a link like `my-wordpress.com/see?pass=0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661` to see private posts as if they were registered. Is that possible? How do I achieve that?
Thank you

Comment: You should never trust $_SERVER[' HTTP_REFERER'], it can be easily faked by the user.
Since you are using wordpress, im sure it should be a better way to manage that.

Comment: I actually can, if the HTTP_REFERER should use the real password, anyone who wanted to fake that password should know the real one, thus granted access to the site.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great way of doing things, but if you really want to handle it like this, you would simply need to validate the "pass" data against whatever your password is on the "private website." Something like...

```
<?php
$myPass = '0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661';
if ($_GET['pass'] == $myPass) {
   // Correct!
} else {
   // Wrong
}
?>
```

Edit: Ideally you would have a piece of software that validates the code at entry and creates a wordpress session for the user. That would be more complex though.

Comment: Thank you, that's the approach I'm looking for. Going to Google that and come back.